# Create multi-line cell in LibreOffice calc with concat function

Tags: libreoffice-calc

To create a multi-line cell manually, I use CTRL+ENTER. I would like to create a multi-line cell using the concat function. Does anyone know what value I have to include in concat that is equivalent to CTRL+ENTER?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try `CHAR(10)` like as `="foo" & CHAR(10) & "bar"`

Answer (score 3):

As shown in JohnSUN's comment, use `CHAR(10)`. Ampersands are commonly used for concatenation, but here is the example using `CONCAT` as requested. Enlarge the cell if you can't see the whole result at first.

```
=CONCAT("foo";CHAR(10);"bar")
```

Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/breaking_lines.html